# How to use itertools to remove lines starting with one of a list of strings

Tags: python, python-itertools

I assume this is a good task for Python's `itertools`. But I don't get it which one of it's magic methods I should use here.

The input data

```
kill = ['err A', 'err B', 'err C'] 
lines = ['keep A', 'err B foo', 'err A bar', 'keep B', 'err C foobar']
```

The expected output

```
['keep A', 'keep B']
```

Very conservatively I would solve it like this

```
for e in lines:
     ok = True
     for k in kill:
         if e.startswith(k):
             ok = False
     if ok:
         result.append(e)
```

Can `itertools` help me here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `itertools`, just use a list comprehension. You can convert `kill` to a tuple, and then it can be used as the argument to `startswith()`.

```
killt = tuple(kill)
result = [line for line in lines if not line.startswith(killt)]
```

Comment: `startswith()` can be passed a tuple of possible prefixes, instead of passing a generator to `any()`

Answer (score 1):

Barmar already took the obvious one, so here are two `itertools` ones just for fun:

```
from itertools import compress, repeat
from operator import not_

result = list(compress(lines, map(not_, map(str.startswith, lines, repeat(tuple(kill))))))
```

```
from itertools import filterfalse
from operator import methodcaller

result = list(filterfalse(methodcaller('startswith', tuple(kill)), lines))
```